# Проблема с регулярным выражением в javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Выполняю упражнение из "Выразительного Javascript'a". Нужно в нижеследующей строке - `'This dialogue' - 'Marvin' said - 'ain't that good,' - and I'm confused` - при помощи шаблона заменить одинарные кавычки двойными везде, кроме `ain't` и `I'm`. Вот код:

```
var text = "'This dialogue' - 'Marvin' said - 'ain't that good,' - and I'm confused";

console.log(text.replace(/'/g, "\"")); //тут, понятное дело, все работает

console.log(text.replace(/(\w|\S)"(\w|\S)/g, '$1\'$2')); //...а тут происходит обратная замена двойных кавычек одинарными по всей строке
```

Сервис [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#code_1) никаких проблем не видит и генерирует такой же код, что и у меня (( В чем, собственно, дело?

Comment: Что у вас за проблема? Ваше описание проблемы наводит на мысль, что у вас все отлично работает.

Comment: @Visman "...происходит обратная замена двойных кавычек одинарными по всей строке"

Comment: @Visman после второго `.replace` строка приобретает первоначальный вид, т.е. ВСЕ кавычки опять становятся одинарными

Comment: Вообще-то вы в обоих случаях работаете с изначальным текстом, а  не с измененным. Вы результат работы первого реплейса ни куда не присваиваете.

Comment: `console.log(text.replace(/'/g, "\"").replace(/(\w)"(\w)/g, '$1\'$2'));`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что результат первого `.replace` ничему не присваивался. Вот так все заработало:

```
var text = "'This dialogue' - 'Marvin' said - 'ain't that good,' - and I'm confused";

var textReplaced = text.replace(/'/g, "\"");

console.log(textReplaced.replace(/(\w|\S)"(\w|\S)/g, '$1\'$2'));
```